# Mongoose hides properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using basic class to encapsulate Mongoose. Even though my query correctly returns the `User` I can't access its properties directly. Following code prints user but prints user.email as undefined.

**PROBLEM:**

When I use `console.log('User from DB: '+  dbUser);` I see full saved user. However When I try to access dbUser.email I get undefined

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, index: {unique: true, sparse: true}},
    password: String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default:Date.now },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
class Database{

    static async getUser(userId) {
        const user = await User.find(userId);
        return user;
    }
}

async function run() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/stack');
    await Device.remove();
    await User.remove();

    const user = new User({'email':'email@address.com','password':'plainsecret'});
    const newUser = await user.save();
    console.log('New User: ',newUser);
    console.log('Email: ' + newUser.email);
    const dbUser = await Database.getUser(newUser._id);
    console.log('User from DB: '+  dbUser);
    console.log('User email from DB: ' + dbUser.email); //undefined???

    return newUser
}

run().then( (user) => {

    console.log('Done' + user);
    process.exit(0);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Exception' + err);
    process.exit(0);
})
```

Comment: Did you check that user is actually saved on db ? If not, there might be some issues with your `User` schema definition.

Comment: When I print `console.log('User from DB: '+  dbUser);` I see full saved user. However I try to access dbUser.email I get undefined

Comment: No, I mean, did you actually check the db with another tool ? Mongoose by default returns the object you provided for save.

Comment: `const dbUser = await Database.getUser(newUser._id);` gets the user fromDB and I can print it and see it. YES I also checked with Robo3T and YES it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like just haven't described some fields in your model. And if don't mongoose won't add these fields in query response object. Are you sure that you added email field in User model?

Comment: But when I print dbUser I see all properties of it. I can see it live in Mongodb. But can't access `email` property from the code.

Comment: I added model. I tried this code with Mongoose 5.0.3 on NodeJS v9.3.0

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass `virtuals: true` option to your schema definition.

> Now, mongoose will call your getter function every time you access the
>   fullName property:
>
> `console.log(axl.fullName); // Axl Rose`
>
> If you use toJSON() or
>   toObject() (or use JSON.stringify() on a mongoose document) mongoose
>   will not include virtuals by default. Pass { virtuals: true } to
>   either toObject() or toJSON().

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals

Answer (score -1):

It was a typo error from my side. Since `User.find()` returns an array therefore when I tried to print it didn't work. Corrected code should be `User.findById()`